# Formula for solutions of a cubic equation

Tags: cubics

I am looking for a simplified formula for a cubic equation in the form:

$$Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$$

That solves for roots $r_1, r_2 $, and $r_3$ when the discriminant is positive and $r$ when it is negative. I am not looking for the complex roots or when the discriminant is zero.

Thanks in Advance,

Zach Hilman

Comment: I am not sure how much 'simpler' you can get, as you've given me a general cubic to begin with. I suggest you Google "Cardano's formula" and begin there. It will give you three conditions for the discriminant, one of them should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Thank you! :) It was appreciated.

Comment: Cool, glad to have helped.